# Android - Service, Boot and check time

Tags: android, time, broadcastreceiver, boot

I have an android app, and I want that the user can decide when (day,hour,and minute) to do something.
So, I have to:
1) start a service when the android phone boots and when the user runs the app (for example after the installation)

2) check (how? how many often?) if the current time is the time choosed by the user

3) run a method if the time is right.

I searched a lot, and I'm a bit confusing...
I found that I have to use a `BroadcastReceiver` to check when the phone boots,then start an `IntentService` to have a background process that's check if the time is a "choosen time" and then call the method.
Am I right?

But how do I check the time? How many often should I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right. You can use a `BroadcastReceiver` to check for boot. As for the chosen time, I recommend that you use the `AlarmManager` class to have your Service run at a particular time or interval.

ref: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: OrhanC1 is correct (sorry, can't make comments yet). As an example: [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=edu.simpson.obryan.projects) (play store) Source is: [here](https://github.com/ergobot/CyNotify) (github). Lastly, when using AlarmManager for kitkat be aware of the notes for sdk 19 or higher (4.4) found: (google Android 4.4 APIs new version notes) Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sean, your code was very useful to me, thank you :)